# Accessing Metadata of specific Google bigquery dataset using SImba JDBC Driver

Tags: google-bigquery, teiid, simba

Here is what I have done so far:
We are using Simba Google BigQuery JDBC driver (version 41_1.2.0.1) in Teiid WildFly server to connect to bigequery. 
We are using below connection URL.
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;OAuthType=2;ProjectId=xyz

Here is what I am looking for:
We need to connect to specific dataset using connectionURL and fetch metadata only of that dataset.

To achieve above I have also tried to use DefaultDataset parameter that is  available and even after using it in Connection URL, Driver is fetching metadata of all datasets available inside mentioned project.

Problem with above:
This really slows down the process of deploying VBD via Teiid.
I think this is mainly due to multiple datasets as when I try to connect to a project with only one dataset, the same us done just in seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code and where in there you assume the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/using/connectionurl.htm) for building the connection URL for the JDBC driver the format for the connection URL is:

```
jdbc:bigquery://[Host]:[Port];ProjectId=[Project];OAuthType=[AuthValue];[Property1]=[Value1];[Property2]=[Value2];...
```

Looking at the options for the [configuration parameters](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/options/intro-online.htm) there is no way to connect to a single dataset only. The [DefaultDataset](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/defaultdataset.htm) only prepopulates the references to tables within that dataset so you can use unqualified table names in your code. The rest of the datasets will still be accessible.